# How to include endpoint in Jmeter results .xml file?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am outputting results from 30 tests to a single xml file.
Currently the file includes latency, connection time, and whether it returned OK. I want the endpoint I am hitting to also be shown. My tests run in sequence and output to a single file.

[image: Result Configuration]

[image: Results file]

Answer (score 1):

It's `Save URL` checkbox:

[image]

---

You can also achieve the same by amending JMeter [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) like:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

and others set to `false`

Put your changes to *user.properties* file, JMeter restart will be required to activate the changes.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)